# Yocto wildcards [^*] not working as expected

Tags: shell, yocto

I have a shell function inside yocto that moves files before creating the final image like that:

```
cp -avR  ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr/mystuff/.[^.]*  ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/home/root/
```

This should apparently copy everything starting with `.` but not `..` but it is copying everything under `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr/mystuff/../`

I've also test with mv but the wildcard **`[^*]`** is not working either. 
Has anyone any clue about what is happening? Is standard bash shell being used or it is interpreted somehow before being executed?

**EDIT 0:** 
I've solved it by using:

```
find ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr/mystuff/ -name ".[^.]*" -exec mv -t ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/home/root/ {} \+
```

Nevertheless, I will appreciate any answer about the previous questions.

Comment: outside a character class the `.` means any character, within `[]` using the `^` for negate, it means a period. Try `\.[^.]` instead

Comment: It is expanding to `..` as well:


    `mv: cannot move '/home/ss/tmp/work/i_64-poky-linux/test-image-x11/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/mystuff/..' to '/home/ss/tmp/work/i_64-poky-linux/test-image-x11/1.0-r0/rootfs/home/root/..': Directory not empty`